# session.getAttribute returns null

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'am using jsp and servlet to realize the authentication before any access to the application 
The is the code of my doPost method:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        Account account;

        try {

            //Checking if the user already exists
            account = accountBesinessLocal.findByLogin(String.valueOf(username));
            if (account != null) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "[User exists:{0}]", username);
                if (accountBesinessLocal.authentificateUser(String.valueOf(username), String.valueOf(password))) {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    System.out.println(session);
                    session.setAttribute("username", account.getLogin());       
                    session.setAttribute("password", account.getPassword());  
                    System.out.println("this "+session.getAttribute(username)+" is connected");
                    response.sendRedirect(home.xhtml");
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("erreur", "Incorrect Authentication");
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginForm.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("erreur", "Incorrect Authentication");
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "[User does not exist:{0}]", username);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginForm.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

When i try to get the login of the user conneced with `session.getAttribute(username);`
it returns null.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

```
session.getAttribute("username")
```

and not

```
session.getAttribute(username)
```

the value of username is whatever the user has entered in the login input field. It's not `"userame"`.

Side note: your code doesn't compile, s you might be running code that isn't the one ou posted.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's usefull and working well. About the code i've posted am running it and it's working too.

Comment: `response.sendRedirect(home.xhtml");` doesn't compile in your code. It's missing a double quote.

Comment: You're right but it was a mistyped. I thought something else is wrong.